# Java Calendar - biweekly on special days

Tags: java, calendar, quartz-scheduler

How can I create Java calendar which will point on Tuesday, Wednesday at 5:30 pm, every two weeks.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Should it be two separate calendars? One for Tuesday and second for Wednesday? how can get every two weeks?

I googled it, but has not found any example.

Can you please hep?

Comment: Out of curiosity: have you considered using Joda Time? It has facilites for such constructs.

Comment: @fge, I need it as calendar for further usage in quartz.

Comment: I have added `quartz-scheduler` as a tag: chances are it has this sort of mechanisms in place already

Comment: See [CronTrigger](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger)

Comment: @mishadoff, it doesn't help, I verified it already.

Comment: On the other hand, if your job is purely Java based, you can always check the result of `cal.getWeekYear() % 2`...

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 3):

```
  Calendar startWed = Calendar.getInstance();
  startWed.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.WEDNESDAY);
  startWed.set(Calendar.HOUR, 17);
  startWed.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
  Calendar startThu = Calendar.getInstance();
  startThu.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.THURSDAY);
  startThu.set(Calendar.HOUR, 17);
  startThu.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

  for (int i = 0; i++ < 100;)
  {
     startWed.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7 * 2); // each 2 weeks
     startThu.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7 * 2); // each 2 weeks
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have just to use the number of the

> WEEK_OF_YEAR  % 2 *[*== *or* !=*]* 0

Answer (score 0):

## Using java.time

The modern way is with the java.time classes rather than the troublesome old legacy classes such as `Calendar`.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

## `TemporalAdjuster`

The [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) interface provides for classes that can make adjustments to date-time values. The [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) class provides several handy implementations. One gets the next desired day-of-week you specify with the [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum.

```
LocalDate nextOrSameTuesday = today.with( TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame( DayOfWeek.TUESDAY );
LocalDate nextOrSameWednesday = today.with( TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame( DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY );
```

Get succeeding weeks by adding a number of weeks.

```
LocalDate followingTuesday = nextOrSameTuesday.plusWeeks( 1 );
```

To get a moment, an actual point on the timeline, apply your desired time-of-day along with a time zone to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

```
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.of( 17 , 30 );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( nextOrSameTuesday , localTime, z );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).